# Phonegap InAppBrowser navigation bar disappears after compiling

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I have used the InAppBrowser plugin to open external webpage links in my Phonegap app. When using the Phonegap development app to preview, everything seems to work fine. The navigation bar appears over the external page after clicking on the external links and to close the page I press the 'Done' button and I am returned to the previous page within my app.

However when I compile my app for both Android and iOS, the navigation bar disappears and I have no way to get back to the app without closing it down. I can use the hardware back button to return on Android, but this is not ideal and still does not solve the iOS problem.

My javascript to open the links look like this:

```
function openURL(urlString){
myURL = encodeURI(urlString);
window.open(myURL, '_blank', 'toolbar=yes');
```

My html to call the javascript looks like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick="openURL('http://www.meningitisnow.org')">www.meningitisnow.org</a>
```

How can I prevent the navigation bar from disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue, turned out the code was fine however the phonegap app was not initialising, so it could not access the relevant inAppBrowser plugin, or any other for that matter.

I created a new project using the latest version of Cordova CLI (4.3 at present) rather than phonegap and transferred the app content and files across to the new project ensuring they conformed to the new project structure.

I also had to manually install the required cordova plugin as they are no longer included like with the old phonegap method:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Now all works fine.